# Cosine Fourier series solution of semi-major axis nonlinear integral equaton

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, integral-equations

Consider an integral equation 
$$
\frac{1}{z(t)}=f(t)+\alpha\int_0 ^\infty \cos(ts)z(s)\,ds 
$$

I am required to solve for $z(t)$. I approached this problem by considering the integral on right hand side as cosine transform of $z(t)$. So that the integral equation becomes
$$
\frac{1}{z(t)}=f(t)+(2\pi\alpha^2)^{1/2}z(t)
$$

We can now solve for $z(t)$. Is this the correct way to solve the problem? If not, can anybody help me solve it?